# Помогите с задачой, пожалуйста! Все никак не получается(

Tags: python

Два ближайших числа
Дан список целых чисел, содержащий как минимум два элемента. Найдите в нём два ближайших элемента (то есть два элемента с минимальной абсолютной разностью). Изменять список при этом нельзя.

Входные данные

В единственной строке входных данных задан список целых чисел, не превосходящих по модулю 231.

Выходные данные

Программа должна вывести два числа: индексы двух элементов списка, абсолютная величина разности которых минимальна.

Примеры
Ввод

```
7 0 4 2 5 9
```

Вывод

```
2 4
```

Вот мой код:

```
a=list(map(int, input().split()))
ans_i=0
ans_j=1
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(a)):
        if abs(a[i]-a[j])<abs(a[ans_i]-a[ans_j]):
        ans_i=i
        ans_j=j
print(ans_i,ans_j)
```

Где ошибка?

Comment: Ошибка в отсутствии табуляции после `if`, если добавить табуляцию, то всё правильно считает

Comment: То есть после if нужно сделать по 4 пробела вправо?

Comment: Что происходит, когда ты запускаешь код?

Comment: Мне уже помог пользователь  
CrazyElf
 Он нашел ошибку. Но спасибо из вашу помощь

Comment: @AndrewCool Ну да, после `if` следом должны быть отступы в следующих двух строчках. Да, по 4 пробела.

Comment: Я не зря спросил, что происходит после запуска. У тебя выскакивает ошибка. И если бы ты её прочитал, то сам бы понял, в чем проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если вот так?

```
a=list(map(int, input().split()))
ans_i=0
ans_j=1
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(a)):
        if abs(a[i]-a[j])<abs(a[ans_i]-a[ans_j]):
            ans_i=i
            ans_j=j
            print(ans_i,ans_j)
```

Обратите внимание на пробелы.

Comment: принт зря сдвинули

Comment: У него там три пары чисел подходят. Потому не зря... Если вернуть принт на место то покажет только последнее вхождение чисел.

Comment: Если разницы при выбранном порядке обхода будут уменьшаться, ваш код может вывести много пар ненужных  a = [1,10,9,8,7]